# Why can I see PriorityQueue elements with an Iterator, but not with poll?

Tags: java, priority-queue

I have the following Java code, which creates a `PriorityQueue` and adds some elements to it:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out);
        PriorityQueue<Integer> q = new PriorityQueue<>();

        Integer[] integers = new Integer[10];
        Integer[] integers1 = new Integer[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            integers[i] = i;
            integers1[i] = i + 10;
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < integers.length; i++) {
            q.add(integers[i]);
            q.add(integers1[i]);
        }

        out.println(q.size());

        for(int i = 0; i < integers.length; i++)
            out.println(q.poll());

        out.close();
    }    
}
```

In this code segment `q.size()` return the size of the queue, which is `20`. However, when I retrieve elements using the `poll()` function in the last loop, it only retrieves the first 10 elements. However, when I use an `Iterator` to access the elements, it retrieves all the elements from the queue. It seems like the `poll()` method always retrieves half of the elements in the queue.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 3):

Your for loop has the wrong bounds here:

```
for(int i = 0; i < integers.length; i++)
    out.println(q.poll());
```

You've added `integers.length + integers1.length` elements to the priority queue, but you're only looping `integers.length` times. Try changing this to use a while loop:

```
while (!q.isEmpty())
    out.println(q.poll());
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You add 20 elements:

```
                          10
                     _____________
                    /             \
for (int i = 0; i < integers.length; i++) {
    q.add(integers[i]);        \________________ x 2
    q.add(integers1[i]);       /
}
```

But you only retrieve 10 elements:

```
                          10
                     _____________
                    /             \
for(int i = 0; i < integers.length; i++)
    out.println(q.poll());    ------------  x 1
```

To drain the priority queue completely, do:

```
while (!q.isEmpty())
    out.println(q.poll());
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `integers.length` is equal to 10. That's the break condition in your last for-statement.